# Force an MDX Calculated Measure to calculate at a specific dimension level before aggregating?

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I have Dimensions called Client, Case, and Person. Person has a hierarchy of Rank. I also have an Hours measure, and a calculated measure called Proportion that, when the Person's rank is Owner, calculates their proportion of all Owner hours. e.g if a Case has 2 Owners with 5 hours and 15 hours each, then the calculated measure below creates a 0.25 and a 0.75 respectively.

`IIF( [Person].[Rank].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Person].[Rank].&[Owner], Measures.[Hours] / sum(([Person].[Person].[Person], [Person].[Rank].&[Owner]), (Measures.[Hours])),  NULL)`

If I have Case and Person.Rank on my rows, this produces the desired values. However if I remove case and add Client, the Proportion is different as its summing at the Client level and then calculating, rather than calculating at the Case level. I have a few measures derived from this, e.g. Revenue * Proportion and Expenses * Proportion that need to be calculated at the Case level and then those values summed at the Person and Client level. 100% credit for a small amount but 50% credit for a large amount results in different totals depending on what level these values are aggregated.

What I need this measure to do is to calculate at the Case level, but so far adding Case (in tuples, crossjoins, sets as Case.Case.currentmember, Case.Case.Case, * Case.Case, etc) in all their possible combinations either has no effect, or produces the wrong value.

Is there a specific function in MDX that can do this?